# twitter authentication in rails app - logging off

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, twitter

I've implemented twitter authentication in my rails app, on my local dev box. However I'm not able to get the application to log off.  Isn't it enough to clear these two cookies?
remember-token and -twitterauth-session?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specifics of Twitter authentication but generally you should invoke  the `reset_session` method in your controller.